# How can I import xml data via the BCC into ATG?

Tags: java, atg

I need to load category and/or product assets into ATG via the BCC. The source data is in XML format.

- I want a scheduler to run in such a way that it should auto-create a project and send an email to a client for approval.
- When the client approves the xml file, then run the scheduler to input the xml file's data into the BCC.

I will be using : `SingletonSchedulableService` for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `SingletonSchedulableService` is the smallest part of your problem. What format will your XML file be in? Will it contain `add-item` definitions for all the things you need to load or is it a non-ATG based XML file? Have a look at `TemplateParser` for loading XML files that follow the `add-item` definitions. As for sending emails and approving them. Will the email simply notify the 'client' and they log in to the BCC to approve?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the sample code that is on `Publishing.base/sample-code/ca-import-sample-code.jar`.

There is a class file named `ProgramaticImportService.java` and a `.properties` on config.

You only needs to extend and code your specific rules (like sending an email).

This class will create a project for you and will call your method, that will read a XML in any format, and everything you create inside this method, like `repository.createItem("product");`, `repository.updateItem(item);` or `repository.addItem(item);` will be "packed" inside the created project. So, you will only need to send an e-mail and wait for the project be approved.

This can auto-approve the project too. Check it.